# Change SD card back to normal storage

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card

I was cleaning up some files on my phone and saw that I have the SD card set as internal storage. As I understand it, this means that the SD card is considered part of the Android filesystem.

This SD card had a problem a few months ago and I had to reformat it, losing the data on it at the time. For this reason I would prefer that it be treated as a normal SD storage device.

Can I convert it back to normal storage, even if it has some apps installed onto the SD card? Will I lose the app data?

Comment: try [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/android-12-sd-card-formatted-as-internal-storage-how-to-undo-and-remove.4533463/post-87900569) (untested)